# how to get COUNT -1 in sybase

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I am trying to get number of records minus 1 from a table based on a condition in sybase database.

I tried with the following query.

```
SELECT COUNT(LastOccurrence)-1 
from alerts.status where (LastOccurrence >= getdate - 1000)
go
```

Results in the following error

> ERROR=Parse failure on line 1 of statement 'SELECT COUNT(LastOccurrence)-1 from
>   alerts.status where (LastOccurrence >= getdate - 1000)...', at or near '-'

Comment: I think it should be `getdate()` not `getdate`

Comment: If I remove -1 then it's working fine and I am getting count total value.

Comment: `select count(column) -vi 1` works on my ASE 15.5 system, but the where clause is problematic(subtracting `int` from `datetime` without conversion).  What Sybase database & version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your query like this

```
select count(LastOccurrence) -1
from alerts.status
where LastOccurrence >= dateadd(dd,-1000,getdate())
```